# Personal medical expense manager

Tags: finance

Does anyone have any recommendations on software to use to track medical expenses? I’m using Windows, but I would prefer a Web app.

Ideally I would like to be able to enter a bill logging the Dr, patient, my $ responsibility, and date of service.  I would then like to enter payments toward these and be able to get a snapshot of outstanding bills and how much is left to owe.

I have medical bills piling up everywhere and trying to get organized.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Windows, but would actually prefer web if available